# Access cookies immediately without causing duplication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

Basically, I am trying to get a string value from cookie..

If I read it from just request.. I can get the value fine.
Except for the first page load as the response hasn't gone to the client and back, so request doesn't have the value I just set.

However, strangely.. if I access Response and check if it exists (aka value just set).. I can get the value out. But it leads to some strange bug(?) where the cookie becomes duplicated in the request on next return.

On the second request back.. the value is read from the blank duplicated request cookie instead. (aka, cookie value does not work)

**SAVE**

```
var request = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
var response = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;

//STORE VALUES TO COOKIE
HttpCookie hc = new HttpCookie("myCookie");
hc.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
hc.Value = "MYVALUE";

request.Cookies.Add(hc);
response.Cookies.Add(hc);
```

**READ**

```
public static string GetAdvancedCookieValue(this UrlHelper url, string cookieName)
{
    var request = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
    var response = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;

    // Accessing Response allows me to get value just set.. but leads to duplicate cookies (with blank data -causing blank return later)
    if (response.Cookies[cookieName] != null && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.Cookies[cookieName].Value) == false)
        return response.Cookies[cookieName].Value;
    if (request.Cookies[cookieName] != null && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Cookies[cookieName].Value) == false)
        return request.Cookies[cookieName].Value;

    return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what ever reason, doing the null check `response.Cookies[cookieName] != null` seems to create the cookie... so I added a check that if the value is null, then remove it. So as to not post a blank cookie replacement to the client.

I can now access the most recent value, including those recently added to response, without wiping out cookie values.

```
    public static string GetAdvancedCookieValue(UrlHelper url, string cookieName)
    {
        var request = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var response = url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (response.Cookies[cookieName] != null)
        {
            if (response.Cookies[cookieName].Value == null)
                response.Cookies.Remove(cookieName);
            else
                return response.Cookies[cookieName].Value;
        }

        if (request.Cookies[cookieName] != null && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Cookies[cookieName].Value) == false)
            return request.Cookies[cookieName].Value;

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Save method you should check if the cookie with that name is already in the collection.

something like this:

```
var cookie = response.Cookies[hc.Name];
if (cookie == null) {
    response.Cookies.Add(hc);
} 
else
{
    cookie.Value = hc.Value;
    cookie.Expires = hc.Expires;
}
```

Remember that all cookies from the `Request.Cookies` collection are copied to the `Response.Cookies` collection. If you don't check for its existence before adding a cookie you'll end up with two cookies of the same name.

Comment: The cookies in response do not exist until I add one. I thought adding to response should overwrite existing ones with that name anyway? I've found a work around, although not sure its ideal.

Comment: I tried this code anyway, just incase I missed something and it does not work :( Appreciate the help though!

Answer (score -1):

With both cookie collections the way to check if a cookie exists is to check the name against the cookies collection AllKeys property.

Comment: I should add do not use add to add a cookie use set. If the cookie exists it will be overwritten, if it does not exist it will be added. The add method just adds the cookie therefore allowing duplicates.